# Bind SelectedValue of UserControl to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

In my solution; I have two projects:  One is a WPF UserControl Library, and the other is a WPF Application.

The usercontrol is pretty straightforward; it's a label and a combo box that will show the installed printers.

In the WPF application; I want to use this usercontrol.  The selected value will be stored in user settings.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the proper binding to work.  What I need to happen is to be able to set the SelectedValue of the UserControl when the MainWindow loads; as well as access the SelectedValue of the UserControl when I go to save my settings.

My code is below, could someone point me in the right direction?

PrintQueue user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControls.PrintQueue"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:wpfControls="clr-namespace:WpfControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <wpfControls:PrintQueueViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Selected Printer:"></Label>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PrintQueues, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" Width="200" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedPrinterName, Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Print Queue Codebehind:

```
public partial class PrintQueue : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentPrinterNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentPrinterName", typeof (string), typeof (PrintQueue), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string CurrentPrinterName
    {
        get { return (DataContext as PrintQueueViewModel).SelectedPrinterName; }
        set { (DataContext as PrintQueueViewModel).SelectedPrinterName = value; }
    }


    public PrintQueue()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PrintQueueViewModel();
    }
}
```

PrintQueue View Model:

```
public class PrintQueueViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<System.Printing.PrintQueue> printQueues;
    public ObservableCollection<System.Printing.PrintQueue> PrintQueues
    {
        get { return printQueues; }
        set
        {
            printQueues = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => PrintQueues);
        }
    }


    private string selectedPrinterName;
    public string SelectedPrinterName
    {
        get { return selectedPrinterName; }
        set
        {
            selectedPrinterName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedPrinterName);
        }
    }

    public PrintQueueViewModel()
    {
        PrintQueues = GetPrintQueues();
    }


    private static ObservableCollection<System.Printing.PrintQueue> GetPrintQueues()
    {
        var ps = new PrintServer();
        return new ObservableCollection<System.Printing.PrintQueue>(ps.GetPrintQueues(new[]
            {
                EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local,
                EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections
            }));
    }
}
```

Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfControls="clr-namespace:WpfControls;assembly=WpfControls" xmlns:wpfApp="clr-namespace:WPFApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <wpfApp:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <wpfControls:PrintQueue CurrentPrinterName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.PrinterName, Mode=TwoWay}"></wpfControls:PrintQueue>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Main Window View Model:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string printerName;

    public string PrinterName
    {
        get { return printerName; }
        set
        {
            printerName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => PrinterName);
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        PrinterName = "Lexmark T656 PS3";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Controls in a library need to expose DependencyProperties that you can bind to in your view. Just like WPF's `TextBox` exposes a `Text` property.

Your `PrintQueue` control doesn't expose anything, and instead keeps all its state in a viewmodel that nothing outside can access. Your `MainWindowViewModel` has no way of getting at the stuff inside `PrintQueueViewModel`.

You need to expose `SelectedPrinterName` as a DependencyProperty in the code behind of your PrintQueue xaml. Then in MainWindow.xaml you can bind it to `MainWindowViewModel.PrinterName`.

If you want to user ViewModels all the way through instead, then `MainWindowViewModel` should be creating `PrintQueueViewModel` itself so it can access the properties within.

As per your update / comment:

Unfortunately DependencyProperties don't work like that. The getters/setters aren't even used most of the time, and they should ONLY update the property itself. You're sort of halfway between two worlds at the moment.

If I were in your position, and assuming you can change the library so PrintQueue.xaml  doesn't have a hardcoded VM instance in the view, I would just create the PrintQueueViewModel yourself. That's how MVVM is supposed to work:

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public PrintQueueViewModel PrintQueue { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        PrintQueue = new PrintQueueViewModel();
        PrintQueue.SelectedPrinterName = "Lexmark T656 PS3";
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfControls="clr-namespace:WpfControls;assembly=WpfControls" xmlns:wpfApp="clr-namespace:WPFApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <wpfApp:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <wpfControls:PrintQueue DataContext="{Binding PrintQueue}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Again though, control libraries generally don't have view models, and expose their state via dependency properties since they're designed to be used in XAML.

Component libraries may expose view models, but in that case they wouldn't hard code the view model in the view.

Did you write the library? If not, how did the author expect people to use it?

Comment: Well actually it's as simple as PrintQueue.DataContext as PrintQueueViewModel, but i agree that it's better to add a typed property on the UserControl. I don't know if the SelectedValue binding of the ComboBox will actually work as is.

Comment: @Gaz; I just updated the code per your suggestions; but still no luck.  I don't have any binding errors thrown; and putting a breakpoint on the setter of CurrentPrinterName shows that it's not even being hit.  Am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 0):

I think with this small changes everything should work

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PrintQueues, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Width="200" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPrinter, Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>


private System.Printing.PrintQueue selectedPrinter;
public System.Printing.PrintQueue SelectedPrinter
{
    get { return selectedPrinter; }
    set
    {
        selectedPrinter = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedPrinter);
    }
}
```

Now from the main window you can modify SelectedPrinter on the viewmodel and the change should be reflected on the view

```
(PrintQueue.DataContext as PrintQueueViewModel).SelectedPrinter = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and your bindings of the `PrintQueueView` to the corresponding view model work fine. Your problem is that the `MainWindowViewModel` does not know about the `PrintQueueViewModel` and thus cannot retrieve the value of the selected printer when the main window closes (I guess that is the scenario you want to implement).

The quickest solution to your problem would be to do the following steps:

1. In MainWindow.xaml, give `PrintQueue` a `Name` so you can access it in the code behind
2. In MainWindow.xaml.cs, override the `OnClosing` method. In it you can retrieve the view model as follows: `var viewModel = (PrintQueueViewModel)PrintQueue.DataContext;`. After that you can retrieve the selected value and save it or whatever.
3. In the `MainWindow` constructor after `InitializeComponent`, you can retrieve your saved value from a file and set it on the `PrintQueueViewModel` by retrieving it the same way as in the previous step.

Whole code in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Retrieve your selected printer here; in this case, I just set it directly
        var selectedPrinter = "Lexmark T656 PS3";
        var viewModel = (PrintQueueViewModel)PrintQueue.DataContext;
        viewModel.SelectedPrinterName = selectedPrinter;
    }
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = (PrintQueueViewModel)PrintQueue.DataContext;
        var selectedPrinterName = viewModel.SelectedPrinterName;
        // Save the name of the selected printer here
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Please remember that the major point of view models is the ability to unit-test GUI logic and to disconnect GUI appearance and logic. Your view models should not be able to retrieve all the possible printers of your system but should obtain these values by e.g. Dependency Injection. I would advise you to read about SOLID programming.